# ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value while passing CLOB as part of a UDT Array

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to pass an User defined type (UDT) as an input parameter to an Oracle Stored Procedure

The UDT array - **FILTER_EXPR_TBL**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE            schema.FILTER_EXPR_TBL AS TABLE OF schema.FILTER_EXPR_T
```

The UDT member - **FILTER_EXPR_T** :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE            schema.FILTER_EXPR_T AS OBJECT  (
                                filter_name        varchar2(50 CHAR),
                                Comparison_opr     varchar2(50 CHAR),
                                Search_value       clob,
                                logical_opr        varchar2(30 CHAR)
                                )
```

My Java code to prepare input for this UDT part:

```
// Preparing filter_expr_t and adding it to an array
            StructDescriptor StructDesc_Filterexpr = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("schema.FILTER_EXPR_T", con);
            Object[] ObjArray = new Object[4];
            ObjArray[0] = "val1";
            ObjArray[1] = "=";
            oracle.jdbc.OracleClob clob =  (oracle.jdbc.OracleClob) con.createClob();
            clob.setString(1,"val2");
            ObjArray[2] = clob;
            ObjArray[3] = "";
            STRUCT filter_expr = new STRUCT(StructDesc_Filterexpr, con, ObjArray);
            STRUCT[] filter_expr_tbl = {filter_expr};
            //Declaring filter_expr_tbl
            ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "schema.FILTER_EXPR_TBL", con);
            ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY( descriptor, con, filter_expr_tbl);
```

where 'con' is the OracleConnection object

The part where I add it to the callable statement :

```
   stmnt.setArray(1, array_to_pass);
```

Closing this question as I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** : We need to create the clob using the same connection that is used to create the callable statement

In this case the clob was created using **con** object. But the callable statement was created without using **con** object

The following

```
OracleConnection con =  (emeaJdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()).unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

OracleCallableStatement stmnt = (OracleCallableStatement) emeaJdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareCall("{call pkg.proc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
```

Should be

```
OracleConnection con =  (emeaJdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()).unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

OracleCallableStatement stmnt = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall("{call pkg.proc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
```